# robot_localization drift

Tags: ros, imu, navigation, ptam, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use robot_localization to fuse IMU with PTAM but I am getting some major drift. The error seems to be compounding.

At first I thought that the axes were not aligned correctly (which still might be the case) but now I am wondering if the PTAM data is being ignored or not factored in.

IMU message:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 20112
  stamp: 
    secs: 1441090194
    nsecs: 749087915
  frame_id: usb_cam
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 31.8292968996
      y: 15.1699469361
      z: -236.728859078
    orientation: 
      x: 0.726365842025
      y: 0.0331459598161
      z: -0.0598464211576
      w: 0.683895031977
  covariance: [0.0039018500775288606, 0.0027630803033894093, 0.007831431075466348, 0.00037953225698867527, 0.0012029410262677585, 0.0008225141417525416, 0.0027630803033894093, 0.0022154257522649786, 0.005748820203067354, 0.0004981530611692311, 0.0008370959001320362, 0.00021214889413358968, 0.007831431075466348, 0.005748820203067352, 0.016284114101305945, 0.0008166119036448137, 0.002352189342863207, 0.0015354683751600184, 0.0003795322569886803, 0.0004981530611692337, 0.0008166119036448272, 0.00044415715572847697, 0.00014435743999326682, 0.0004755561972274128, 0.0012029410262677585, 0.0008370959001320371, 0.0023521893428632076, 0.00014435743999326628, 0.0005786599694969616, 8.747369640226204e-05, 0.0008225141417525225, 0.00021214889413362665, 0.0015354683751599768, 0.00047555619722741335, 8.747369640224455e-05, 0.0014638212613628672]
---
```

IMU message (time delay between last message):

```
---
header: 
  seq: 415116
  stamp: 
    secs: 1441090283
    nsecs: 586467584
  frame_id: fcu
orientation: 
  x: 0.0348078489314
  y: 0.0336684433503
  z: 0.620517126138
  w: 0.782696202715
orientation_covariance: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.000315623357892
  y: -0.000284243375063
  z: 0.000455724075437
angular_velocity_covariance: [1.2184696791468346e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2184696791468346e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2184696791468346e-07]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: -0.084431245923
  y: 0.915327310562
  z: 9.66289806366
linear_acceleration_covariance: [8.999999999999999e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.999999999999999e-08, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.999999999999999e-08]
---
```

tf launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom" args="-0.5 0 0 1.5707 0 1.5707 odom usb_cam 100" />
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link fcu 100" />
</launch>
```

And the ekf launch file:

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">

  <param name="frequency" value="30"/>

  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>

  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>

  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>

  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

  <param name="pose0" value="/vslam/pose"/>
  <param name="imu0" value="/mavros/imu/data"/>

  <rosparam param="pose0_config">[true,  true,  true,
                                  true, true, true,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                 true,  true,  true,
                                 false, false, false,
                                 true,  true,  true,
                                 true,  true,  true]</rosparam>


  <param name="pose0_differential" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="false"/>

  <param name="pose0_relative" value="false"/>
  <param name="imu0_relative" value="true"/>

  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>

  <param name="print_diagnostics" value="false"/>

</node>
```

The robot_localization message:

```
    ---
header: 
  seq: 75
  stamp: 
    secs: 1441104536
    nsecs: 404455893
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0327968532627
      y: 0.0107415590331
      z: 0.0672586918467
    orientation: 
      x: 0.000269673528914
      y: -9.62085270466e-05
      z: 0.000620642648884
      w: 0.999999766411
  covariance: [0.25178859948463683, -4.971036727512653e-06, -3.834708230879292e-05, 5.617159792226774e-07, 0.001132411300727592, -0.00016460156245969569, -4.971036727512627e-06, 0.251802630760143, -3.866513136687686e-05, -0.001132338668495088, 6.963000174227653e-07, 0.0005564970580662025, -3.8347082308792896e-05, -3.866513136687682e-05, 0.3528520627453843, 0.00015796138409329648, -0.0005195820989177445, 6.036177571201076e-08, 5.617159792226772e-07, -0.0011323386684950888, 0.00015796138409329648, 0.03157641168651724, 7.257794513246155e-10, 4.91036385931138e-07, 0.0011324113007275926, 6.963000174227649e-07, -0.0005195820989177441, 7.257794513253871e-10, 0.03157641321713827, 1.1834706590470503e-06, -0.0001646015624596956, 0.0005564970580662015, 6.036177571201076e-08, 4.910363859311376e-07, 1.1834706590470499e-06, 0.043689017073481766]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0210921228234
      y: 0.0062526978065
      z: 0.0547688153658
    angular: 
      x: -0.000258302719997
      y: -0.000517417815119
      z: -0.00076631415027
  covariance: [0.06239698790077553, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06239698790077553, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09983517550002659, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2179398991361593e-07, 5.2601439590013494e-33, 3.0621846696809155e-30, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.260143958793435e-33, 1.2179398991361593e-07, 8.22777177602546e-30, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0621846696809866e-30, 8.22777177602553e-30, 1.218204673952421e-07]
---
```

Debug output with IMU turned off:

```
tf_prefix is 
map_frame is map
odom_frame is odom
base_link_frame is base_link
world_frame is odom
transform_time_offset is 0
frequency is 30
sensor_timeout is 0.1
two_d_mode is false
print_diagnostics is false
Subscribed to /vslam/pose (pose0)
    pose0_differential is true
    pose0_rejection_threshold is 1.79769e+308
    pose0_queue_size is 1
    pose0 update vector is [t  t  t  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  f  ]
------ RosFilter::integrateMeasurements ------

Integration time is 1441162630.7626991272
0 measurements in queue.
Filter not yet initialized.

----- /RosFilter::integrateMeasurements ------
WARNING: failed to transform from usb_cam->odom for pose0 message received at 1441162630.990499904. No transform exists from source to target frame.
------ RosFilter::integrateMeasurements ------
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216856/robot_localization-drift/) by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-09-01**:
Can you show me a sample output message (from the EKF)?

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-01**:
Sure. I'll update the question now.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-01**:
@Tom Moore sample output is there now. Let me know if there is anything else that can be of use.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-01**:
BTW I'm using [ethzasl_ptam](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam). Not sure if it is compatible or not.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-01**:
@Tom Moore would it help if all the messages had the same time stamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What happens if you turn off linear acceleration? Also, I would turn of roll, pitch, and yaw for pose0.

**EDIT:**

Run PTAM without anything else running (not even `ekf_localization_node`). Try running the `tf` `tf_monitor` or simply `view_frames`. Now run your transform launch file and do those actions again. Make sure your frames exist and are connected.

One thing you might want to do regardless is use the `tf2_ros` `static_transform_publisher`. The parameters are very similar:

```
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_cam" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom usb_cam" />
```

Note that you no longer specify the period at the end.

**EDIT 2**

You have a `tf` reparenting problem. Something else is publishing a *world*->*usb_cam* transform. You are publishing an *odom*->*usb_cam* transform. No frame can have two parents (it's a tree structure). You should make your static transform go from *odom*->*world* instead of *odom*->*usb_cam*.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-01**:
I turned off linear acceleration for the imu0 and RPY for pose0. This eliminates the drift but now there is no positional movement at all.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-09-01**:
Sounds like PTAM data is being ignored. Try fusing just the PTAM data (comment out the IMU) and see if anything happens. If not, turn on debug mode, run *briefly*, and search for pose0 in the debug output file.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-01**:
@Tom Moore I've added the debug output to the question at the end (more). I am getting this warning: failed to transform from usb_cam->odom for pose0. Looks like I still haven't got tf setup correctly?

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-02**:
@Tom Moore before running the tf launch file it looks like this: world->usb_cam. After it looks like this: world   odom->usb_cam   base_link->fcu. If I try it with tf2 nothing appears to change after launching the file: world->usb_cam. I didn't realize ptam was creating that world node before.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-02**:
That has eliminated (most of) the drift and I think it is now using both sensors. It doesn't seem to be moving right but I will have another look at the tutorial about preparing sensor data and see if I can get that right. Thanks again!

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-09-02**:
@Tom Moore just to check before moving on, the tf tree that is now generated after running ekf has 2 branches with odom at the root of both: odom->base_link->fcu and odom->world->usb_cam. Does this seem right?